# oracle coding sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in the below format

```
g_name amt flag
g1      0     0
g1      0     0
g1     10     1
g1      0     0
g1     15     2
g1      0     0
```

and I would require in the below format

`n1` will have data starting from row where amt hits `1` and it keeps retaining it till the end, similarly `n2` will have data starting from row where amt hits `2` and it keeps retaining it till the end, please help me with any window functions with out needing joins. please.

```
g_name amt flag   n1  n2
g1       0    0    0   0
g1       0    0    0   0 
g1      10    1   10   0
g1       0    0   10   0
g1      15    2   10  15
g1       0    0   10  15
```

Comment: How are the rows ordered? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Unless there is an additional field based on which the order of the rows can be determined, I don't see how this can be done.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and read [ask].

Comment: rows are ordered by week..sorry for missing that info

Answer (score 1):

I added a column for ordering - change as needed. I also added a few more rows with a different `g_name`, presumably this must be done "by `g_name`".

This is a good test case for the `first_value()` analytic function. It has the ability to ignore nulls - so we make the `amt` NULL when `flag` is not 1 (or 2, etc.) and then apply `first_value()` with the proper PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clauses.

```
with
     test_data ( id, g_name, amt, flag ) as (
       select 1, 'g1',  0, 0 from dual union all
       select 2, 'g1',  0, 0 from dual union all
       select 3, 'g1', 10, 1 from dual union all
       select 4, 'g1',  0, 0 from dual union all
       select 5, 'g1', 15, 2 from dual union all
       select 6, 'g1',  0, 0 from dual union all
       select 1, 'g2',  0, 0 from dual union all
       select 2, 'g2',  4, 1 from dual union all
       select 3, 'g2',  3, 2 from dual union all
       select 4, 'g2',  0, 0 from dual
     )
--  end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select id, g_name, amt, flag,
       coalesce (first_value(case when flag = 1 then amt end ignore nulls) 
                 over (partition by g_name order by id), 0) as n1,
       coalesce (first_value(case when flag = 2 then amt end ignore nulls) 
                 over (partition by g_name order by id), 0) as n2          
from   test_data
order by g_name, id
;

 ID G_NAME        AMT       FLAG         N1         N2
--- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  1 g1              0          0          0          0
  2 g1              0          0          0          0
  3 g1             10          1         10          0
  4 g1              0          0         10          0
  5 g1             15          2         10         15
  6 g1              0          0         10         15
  1 g2              0          0          0          0
  2 g2              4          1          4          0
  3 g2              3          2          4          3
  4 g2              0          0          4          3
```

Comment: Hey mathguy, thanks for the answer...however i think i haven't mentioned clearly..so flag variable will never have duplicates (except for zero) it will either be zero or distinct numbers (and to mention additionally data is ordered by week wise let's say) so flag is basically a first instance when he purchases a product, second instance and so on..so n1 for this example should have 10 from 4th row till end similary n2 should have 15 from #5 till end...n3 should have 4 from row #8 till end...similarly for n4

Comment: @Kishore - The info about `flag` is irrelevant (it has no effect on the problem or on the solution I offered). Ordering by week (or by some date column) is fine instead of `id`, adapt as needed. In my test I added a second "customer", I hope you noticed that. The most problematic is your new request (not in the original question!) of having more columns if the `flag` value may be 3, 4, ...  That is simply **impossible** with standard SQL. If you need a variable number of columns, depending on what is found in the data at runtime, you will need dynamic SQL - not a good thing.

Comment: Hi, No no, I will fix columns to certain number let's say 3 ....so irrespective of whether flag has numbers beyond 3 or not i would just create 3 columns n1-n3...how ever my n1 variables should have value populated from that row (where flag=1) with value picked from "amt" variable and it should just keep retaiing it till the end..hope i'm clear ....thanks a lot for your promot replies :)

Comment: @Kishore - then it should be trivial to adapt the solution I provided already. My solution populates two additional columns, `n1` and `n2`. You can easily "copy and paste" and make small modifications to add `n3` and `n4` as needed. Just try!

Comment: Thank You! It worked...i just used this... coalesce (first_value(case when flag = 1 then amt end ignore nulls) 
                 over (partition by g_name order by id), 0) as n1,
       coalesce (first_value(case when flag = 2 then amt end ignore nulls) 
                 over (partition by g_name order by id), 0) as n2... However can you help me understand what is being done exactly....it picks those rows where flag=1 and considers amt everything else is null among these it picks first non null value right? however i'm not able to get how i'm getting zeros for the first few rows.....

Comment: sorry i'm not very comfortable with oracle...i used to work with sas sql

Comment: @Kishore - that is exactly right. The zeros instead of NULL for the first few rows: that's what COALESCE() does. If its first argument is not NULL then that first argument is returned as is, but if the first argument is NULL, the function returns the second argument (which is 0).

Comment: Thanks again! Still one question though...sorry for troubling you so much....need to deliver something in couple hours...i'm aware of coalesce function...so please confirm if this is how it works....while calculating n1 value for first row it takes only one row and processes, for populating n1 value for second row it takes all the preceding rows including 2 and so on..which is why till it hits row where flag=1 there are no ones and beyond that since the preceding rows has one it is getting populated correctly as 10 right? let me know if it's unclear..

Comment: @Kishore - exactly right. What "takes only one row, then the first two rows, etc." is not COALESCE, but the FIRST_VALUE function - it is an "analytic function" and all analytic functions work that way. You can also control which rows are considered (in many, but not all analytic functions); going from the first row to the current row is the default, so it doesn't need to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Yep. Got it. Great. If you don't mind can you help me with this...I gave it a try but it involves creating three variables which is eating up lot of time..so i need to create a column say m1--it should capture value from say amt2 variable when it hits flag=1 for the first time and moving ahead it should keep summing up cumulatively till the end....similar to n1 variable except that instead of retaining the same till the end it should keep calculating cumulative sum...

Comment: my approach---created variable v1 which is basically a dummy =1 when  it hits flag=1 for the first time and it retains till the end as 1..second variable v2 gets value from amt2 when v1= 1 else 0...thrid variable  does a cumulative sum on v2

Comment: @Kishore - What do you mean by "variable"? There are no variables in plain SQL. Are you using PL/SQL (a procedure, function etc.)? - and if so, why? What's wrong with basic analytic functions?

Comment: What i meant by variable is just a column that i'm creating...just like g_name,amt,flag...i'm creating v1,v2 and v3

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies that ordering.  Let me assume that such a column exists.

If so, you can do this with analytic functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when flag = 1 then amt else 0 end) over (order by ??) as n1,
       max(case when flag = 2 then amt else 0 end) over (order by ??) as n2
from t;
```

The `??` specifies the ordering.

Comment: @gordon linoff ...Hey thanks a lot this is working and it is even simpler...thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you please help me with the below question...i need to create a column say m1--it should capture value from say amt2 variable when it hits flag=1 for the first time and moving ahead it should keep summing up cumulatively till the end....similar to n1 variable except that instead of retaining the same till the end it should keep calculating cumulative sum...i'm not allowed to post any questions separately so i'm asking you here only...it would be really helpful.